# Find index value of cell in a sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlwt

```
Product Name
SET I Violations 
Rule 1   0 
Rule 2   5 
Rule 3   0
Total    5

SET II Violations 
Rule 1   2
Rule 2   1 
Rule 3   1 
Total    4

SET III Violations
Rule 1    0 
Rule 2    0 
Rule 3    2 
Total     2
```

I want to find an index of cell containing SET I, SET II, SET III, SET IV and Total.. like in above example SET I at 1,0 Total at 5,0... And rules are not fixed they can increase or decrease

I tried following code :

```py
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    if row_value[0].startswith('SET') :
     print (row_value.row,row_value.column)
```

Above code giving following error :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: use pandas [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: @anky_91 I want to find index of cell starting with SET and Total..I  know how to check if it starts with a string but second part is i want to find index of that string in excel

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the df looks like this after you read using pandas:

```
df=pd.read_excel(file)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Product        Name
0    SET I   Violations
1    Rule 1           0
2    Rule 2           5
3    Rule 3           0
4     Total           5
5    SET II  Violations
6    Rule 1           2
7    Rule 2           1
8    Rule 3           1
9     Total           4
10  SET III  Violations
11   Rule 1           0
12   Rule 2           0
13   Rule 3           2
14    Total           2
```

---

You can then use [`series.str.startswith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) as below and call the index for the `True` rows.

```
df[df.Product.str.startswith('SET')].index
#Int64Index([0, 5, 10], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: No i don't want to find index of string in dataframe..i want to find string in exel sheet..please read my question as i mentioned in example excel SET I is at 1,0 index then Total at 5,0 then SET II at 6,0..i want to find that index

Answer (score 0):

You need to `print` row_num and the column index will be 0 because of if condition

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    if row_value[0].startswith('SET') :
        #because of if condition column index will be 0
        print (row_num,0)
```

if the index is not fixed then you can print the index of element having value 'SET'

```
if 'SET' in row_value:
    print(row_num, row_value.index('SET'))
```

Comment: Yes it  is working..but column value always won't be 0...if i want to find same for a row having column other than 0 what should be the answer ??

Comment: @AkashWarkhade updated the ans. please confirm if this works for you

Comment: @AkashWarkhade you may accept the ans if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

since your values to check 'Rule' and 'Total' are at column index `0`, you can directly print 0,

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
    row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
    if row_value[0].startswith('SET') :
        print(row_value[0],'-(row,col): ',row_num,",0",sep='')
    if row_value[0].startswith('Total') :
        print(row_value[0],'-(row,col): ',row_num,",0",sep='')

  >>
SET I-(row,col): 1,0
Total-(row,col): 5,0
SET II-(row,col): 7,0
Total-(row,col): 11,0
SET III-(row,col): 13,0
Total-(row,col): 17,0
```